# cómo llenar select dinamicos dependientes con javascript cargando datos desde un php con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mvc, php7

Tengo un formulario con 2 selects relacionados:

- Proveedor
- Orden de compra

Por separado cargan bien, pero quiero que al seleccionar el proveedor, se carguen únicamente las órdenes de compra correspondientes al proveedor escogido.

Este es el html que contiene mis "select" en el archivo (vista). Utilizo bootstrap en el lado cliente:

ordencompra.php

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
  <label>Proveedor(*):</label>
  <select id="idproveedor" name="idproveedor" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
    <option value="">seleccione Proveedor</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
  <label>Orden de Compra:</label>
  <select id="oc" name="oc" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
    <option value="">seleccione la Orden de compra</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

El javaScript:
 ordencompra.js

```
$.post("../ajax/ordencompra.php?op=selectProveedor", function(r) {
  $("#idproveedor").html(r);
  $('#idproveedor').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

el php que devuelve las opciones en el archivo ordencompra.ajax:

```
case 'selectProveedor':
  require_once "../modelos/Persona.php";
  $persona = new Persona();

  $rspta = $persona - > listarP();

  while ($reg = $rspta - > fetch_object()) {
    echo '<option value='.$reg - > idpersona.
    '>'.$reg - > nombre.
    '</option>';
  }
  break;
```

El modelo Persona.php, que devuelve los proveedores:

```
public
function listarp() {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM persona WHERE tipo_persona='Proveedor'";
  return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}
```

asi es como tengo distribuido mi proyecto  se me paso mencionar que los datos de el proveedor y de las oc me las debo de traer de una tabla en una base de datos en mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que he visto es que aquí llamas al archivo "ordencompra.php" y en tu descripción indicas que el archivo php que genera las órdenes de compra se llama ordencompra.ajax.

Entrando en el código, en el javaScript: ordencompra.js veo que pasas 
 "selectProveedor" dentro del string de la url:

```
$.post("../ajax/ordencompra.php?op=selectProveedor", function(r) {
  $("#idproveedor").html(r);
  $('#idproveedor').selectpicker('refresh'); 
});
```

Para enviar la variable con el valor seleccionado del select "idProveedor" debería estar así:

```
$.post("../ajax/ordencompra.php?op=" + selectProveedor, function(r) { 
[...]
```

Tampoco veo dónde asignas el valor del select a la variable. Me faltaría, antes del $.post, una línea similar a ésta:

```
let selectProveedor = $( "#idproveedor" ).val();
```

3. Luego, en persona.php tampoco veo dónde se está utilizando la variable que se pasa por $_GET:

```
public function listarp() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM persona WHERE tipo_persona='Proveedor'";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}
```

No sé que campos tiene la tabla persona, pero imagino que sería algo así:

1. Recibo la variable $proveedor_id
2. Si la variable está vacía, ejecuto la consulta devolviendo todos los
   proveedores
3. Si la variable es una id de proveedor, filtro la consulta para
   imprimir los registros correspondientes al proveedor seleccionado
   con una query parecida a ésto:

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM persona 
       WHERE tipo_persona='Proveedor' 
       AND id_proveedor = $proveedor";
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. tienes tu select que cargas al principio ejemplo este donde cargo pises

    <select required id="cmbpais" name="cmbpais" onChange="regiones(this.id)">
              <option value="">Seleccione Pais:</option>
              <?php
             $sqlpais = "SELECT id_pais,pais FROM pp_pais where vigente='S'";
            $querypais = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlpais);

              while ($pais = mysqli_fetch_array($querypais)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$pais['id_pais'].'">'.$pais['pais'].'</option>';
              }
               mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
            </select>

2. segundo tienes el combobox dependiente del que mencione

    <select required id="cmbregion" name="cmbregion" onChange="ciudades(this.id)">
                <option value="">Seleccione Región:</option>
    </select>
3. y en java una funcion como la siguiente para llenar el onchange hace la magia javascript puro 

function ciudades(idSelectOrigen){
    // Obtengo el select que el usuario modifico
    var selectOrigen=document.getElementById(idSelectOrigen);
    // Obtengo la opcion que el usuario selecciono
    var opcionSeleccionada=selectOrigen.options[selectOrigen.selectedIndex].value;
    // Si el usuario eligio la opcion "Elige", no voy al servidor y pongo los selects siguientes en estado "Selecciona estado..."
    if(opcionSeleccionada==0)
    {
        var selectActual=null;
        if(idSelectOrigen == "cmbregion")
            selectActual=document.getElementById("cmbciudad");
        selectActual.length=0;
        var nuevaOpcion=document.createElement("option"); 
        nuevaOpcion.value=0; 
        nuevaOpcion.innerHTML="Seleccione Región:";
        selectActual.appendChild(nuevaOpcion);  
        selectActual.disabled=true;
    }
    // Compruebo que el select modificado no sea el ultimo de la cadena
    else{
        if(idSelectOrigen == "cmbregion")
            var selectDestino=document.getElementById("cmbciudad");
        // Creo el nuevo objeto AJAX y envio al servidor la opcion seleccionada del select origen
        var ajax=nuevoAjax();
        ajax.open("GET", "consultaciudad.php?opcion="+opcionSeleccionada+"&select="+idSelectOrigen, true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange=function() 
        { 
            if (ajax.readyState==1)
            {
                // Mientras carga elimino la opcion "Selecciona Opcion..." y pongo una que dice "Cargando..."
                selectDestino.length=0;
                var nuevaOpcion=document.createElement("option"); 
                nuevaOpcion.value=0; 
                nuevaOpcion.innerHTML="Cargando...";
                selectDestino.appendChild(nuevaOpcion); 
                selectDestino.disabled=true;    
            }
            if (ajax.readyState==4)
            {
                selectDestino.parentNode.innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
            } 
        }
        ajax.send(null);
    }
}
```